# Does the battery discharge detector have a self test function on the B738?

Tags: boeing-737, cockpit-alerts, battery

Does the battery discharge detector on a Boeing 737-800 have a self test function that causes the light (BAT DISCHARGE) to illuminate and extinguish?

I have not found such a thing in the FCOM but been asked by one of my captains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What self-test functions maintenance is able to use is beyond the scope of what Boeing thinks pilots should know about (lest we try to use them in flight & get ourselves in trouble with things we don't entirely understand).  As far as anything that we observe or can trigger as operators, I'm not aware of any such self-test. That *could* be something that the ELEC light would indicate, although offhand I don't recall that being one of the things that light monitors.

Obviously the Lights Test switch will show that the bulbs behind the light itself are working, and if you start the APU without ground power, or have the battery as the only source powering the aircraft for a sustained timeframe (i.e. when terminating the aircraft at the end of the day), then you can observe that the light illuminates -- although under certain conditions like APU start it won't trigger the Master Caution, since illumination then is expected.

But as far as a self-test that causes the light to blink on then off, that doesn't sound like anything I've observed.